# Why substring "com." in GoogleScript convert to "(class)"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-editor, http-status-code-406, intercom

Today, the Google script has stopped representing the line normally.
In case of occurrence of a line "com." or "org." - substring is replaced by a certain class "(class)". How to fix the problem?

```
function myFunction2() {
   var t = "testcom.io";
   t = t + '1';
   t=t;
}
```

screenshot from editor [image]

The logger shows the result as well as you do. But during the debugging, the value of the variable T changes. Because of this error, URL Feth does not work. A full script was written a few months ago and worked until today.

You can look error on the next screenshot. We have var url = 'api.intercom.io';; When we try run function we see

> error 406

and message where var url is changed to api.intercom.io';. In case of occurrence of a line "com." or "org." - substring is replaced by a certain class "(class)" or symbols .

```
function myFunction3() {
  var url = 'https://api.intercom.io';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

look at  [image: screenshot]

Comment: Kindly fix your code typo and provide code where you're using the substring

Comment: My bad, thx, done

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52231226/1595451

Answer (score 0):

I think that `test(class)` is not the value of `t` rather that's the class to which this particular t variable belongs.

You can turn your function into something like this :
[image]

Then check the log to see value of t
[image]

Let me know if you need anymore help.