# How to stop UrlFetchApp from turning "com." substring into (class)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, urlfetch, intercom

I ran an issue when trying to match a request to `api.intercom.com`.

`api.intercom.io` consistently gets changed to `api.inter(class)` when set as a variable and used in the `UrlFetchApp` call but it displays as `api.intercom.io` in the `Logger.log` output.

Screenshots:

[image: code]

[image: Logger.log-output]

[image: Debugger-output]

Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

It only looks "as if" `com.io` is changed to `(class)`. The error is just visual and has nothing to do with why `Urlfetch` is NOT working. Use Stackdriver logging:  `console.log()` for accurate  representation of the string.

#### Related Questions:

- [Intercom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49273513/why-substring-com-in-googlescript-convert-to-class)
- [Http status 406](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52625841/google-app-script-external-api-return-error-406)

Comment: I can confirm that it shows up as expected in the logs. However, the error received when trying to execute `UrlFetchApp.fetch` is `Invalid argument: https://api.inter<?>` which leads me to believe it isn't just a visual thing. Pretty strange no?

Comment: @Joe I believe it's still visual. I also think that the error is 406.